# Confirmation dialog with dynamic message content for h:commandButton

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am trying to create a confirmation dialog for a commandButton in JSF. The message I want to display is "Are you sure you want to deploy to #{deployBean.environmentName}?", where            #{deployBean.environmentName} refers to the selected value of h:selectOneMenu.

I used plain JavaScript in the 'onClick' parameter of h:commandButton to do this. The XHTML code is as follows:

```
<h:commandButton id="deploy" 
value="Deploy" 
action="#{deployBean.deployButtonAction}" 
disabled="#{(!deployBean.checkDeploy and (deployBean.stageComplete or deployBean.stageRunning)) or (deployBean.stageStart)}" 
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to deploy to #{deployBean.environmentName}?');" > 
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="status output detail"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

But the environment name does not get displayed in the confirmation dialog box.

[image: Output of the code]

Please let me know what I'm missing in my code. Or please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Hi! Did you get to try the solution in my answer yet? Did you have any trouble with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, that won't work because the *plain JavaScript* bit you mentioned. =)
You see, JavaScript does not know anything about that `#{deployBean.environmentName}` syntax -- this EL expression is evaluated in the server only once, before the page loads, and that's it.

Even if you do an AJAX update in your `h:selectOneMenu` trying to make sure the value in `deployBean` is set when the button is clicked, the `onclick` will be evaluated only in the client side. So, you can do what you want with plain JavaScript & DOM manipulation, maybe something like this:

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to deploy to ' +
         document.getElementsByClassName('environment-name')[0].value + '?');"
```

And give your `h:selectOneMenu` a `styleClass="environment-name"`.

That should do what you want.

Of course, if you happen to use jQuery in your app, you can make it a bit shorter:

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to deploy to ' +
         $('.environment-name').val() + '?');"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a comprehensive answer. I have a doubt though. Why can't we use 'document.getElementsById'?

Comment: Oh, you can indeed use `document.getElementById()`, you just need to make sure to give an id to the form and use the actual client id (not the component id).